# Non-resolvable parent POM and Could not transfer artifact from/to central repository

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf3hT.jpg)Getting below error in eclipse for spring boot project

Non-resolvable parent POM and Could not transfer artifact from/to central repository and transfer failed for spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.pom

I have tried maven->update project->force update project and tried to delete m2 folder.but failed
Can anyone help on this

Comment: Can you put here the pom, at least the parent part.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you version is wrong.
Missing the release part.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have give version 2

Comment: I have give version 2.1.2 only

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>
```